# Ruby (or Rails): How can I apply a relative URL to a full URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a complete URL, I need to handle every possible kind of valid relative URL, like you might see in an HREF attribute on the page at the first location, or in a `Location:` header.

#### Examples:

Complete:  `http://example.com/foo/bar.html`
Input:     `calico.gif`
Result:    `http://example.com/foo/calico.gif`

Complete:  `http://example.com/foo/bar.html`
Input:     `../x.html`
Result:    `http://example.com/x.html`

Complete:  `http://example.com/foo/bar.html`
Input:     `/robots.txt`
Result:    `http://example.com/robots.txt`

#### Question

How can I reliably handle these sorts of relative URLs? I have to imagine someone has written solid code for this before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require 'uri'
URI::join("http://domain.com/dir", "/images/small/image.png")
URI::join("http://example.com/foo/bar.html", "calico.gif")
...
```

and just call `.to_s` to get a string.

Comment: And as the method will tell you if you try otherwise, you have to start with an absolute URL

Comment: Great! I was playing around `File.join` :)

Comment: Happily, and to my pleasant and mild surprise, this works if the second URL is also an absolute, complete URL.